# How to get distinct documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, unique, distinct, aggregation, cardinality

I have a documents with fields `campaign_id` (not unique), `clicks` (same for each `campaign_id`).
How to count sum of unique `campaign_id`s `clicks`. e.g.

```
campaign_id=1, clicks=2;
campaign_id=2, clicks=3;
campaign_id=1, clicks=2;
```

Sum of unique `campaign_id`'s `clicks` will be 5.

Main idea is to get documents with unique `campaign_ids` and then sum.
How to create such query in Elasticsearch?

Tried to achieve this using filters inside aggregation but filter should be a bucket instead of metrics.

Comment: try aggregate function

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach to this is with [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation) in ES 2.0, using a `max` aggregation first to get a **single value** (since you said that the same `campaign_id` has the same `clicks` value) and then a `sum_bucket` pipeline aggregation to get the final sum:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "campaign_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "one_value": {
          "max": {
            "field": "clicks"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_uniques": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "unique_ids>one_value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes, its possible in version 2.0, but we are still using 1.7.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in 1.7. Pipeline aggregations is one of the main features in 2.0 and users for a long time wanted something like this.